# Is the speaker talking about me or themselves in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, sentence, reading-comprehension

> rilesさん日本語上手いのでもっと自信持っていいと思います 笑

I believe I've more or less gathered the translation, in that they think (someone) should have more confidence because (someone) is good at Japanese, but here's where I'm confused.

Who are they saying is good at Japanese, and who are they saying they believe should have more confidence? I'm not sure how to tell.

Comment: Aren't you the only one got referred in this sentence?

Comment: Yes, so does that mean it's me? I have incredibly minimal Japanese knowledge and this is my first time having an actual conversation with someone in Japanese. I've been using Google to translate the sentences, and it was giving me this: "riles is good at Japanese so I think I can be more confident lol" but that didn't seem right, so I wanted to ask an actual person to make sure. I hope that's okay.

Comment: If not riles, who would they be referring to? Why do you think they might be talking about someone else?

Comment: @Riles , Google translate is SO BAD at translating Japanese. I'd strongly recommend using [deepl](https://www.deepl.com/translator). Which gives, "*riles-san, your Japanese is very good, so I think you should be more confident.*"